# Gremlin OLAP queries on AWS Neptune

Tags: amazon-web-services, graph, olap, gremlin, amazon-neptune

In the AWS Neptune documentation it says it is Apache TinkerPop Gremlin compatible but it only refers to online transaction processing (OLTP) type of graph traversal queries. I haven't seen anything about long-running online analytical processing (OLAP) [GraphComputer](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#graphcomputer) queries.

Is it possible to execute OLAP queries on  graphs stored in AWS Neptune graph database service?

Answer (score 5):

I was at ReInvent and had a chance to talk to Brad about it. For the immediate future it’s all OLTP. only one query per transaction (I.e no semi colons) and must begin with “g.” For your implicit graph.

**Update:** Since GA (June 2018), Neptune supports multiple queries in a single request/transaction.

Comment: this is true, but all queries except the last one must end with .next(); so if a step ends a traversal such as .drop() then no other queries may come after it